# How to insert an "if" formula in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section on my website to display a live price estimates based on a value inputted. I just have have one final bit of formula to add but I'm unsure how to modify the code, I need to introduce a minimum for the variable part of the price (5% of the inputted value or 2, whichever is greater. For example:

`If(curValFloat * 0.05 > 2, curValFloat * 0.05, 2) + 4`

Here's the code that's in use now:

```
var elDeliveryPrice = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
var elOrderValue = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('gb-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

elOrderValue.addEventListener('keyup', _ => {
  let curVal = elOrderValue.value;

  let curValFloat = parseFloat(curVal);
  if (isNaN(curValFloat)) {
    elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = '';
    return;
  }

  elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = formatter.format((curValFloat * 0.05) + 4);
});
```

Comment: `Math.max(curValFloat * 0.05, 2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting this as an answer since stuff in comments gets lost sometimes.*

You can use [Math#max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), which returns the maximum of numbers passed to it.

```
Math.max(curValFloat * 0.05, 2)
```